# How to hide parameters from querystring (url) ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm trying to hide the parameters from the querystrings in my web application.
I have been able to do that by using the session to store temporary variables. So it would work like this:

**1. Click the view profile button:**

```
href="@Url.Action("RedirectWithId", "Redirect", new { act = "ProfileView", ctrl = "User", id = member.Id})"
```

**2. Calls the redirection method and stores the temp data:**

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult RedirectWithId(string act, string ctrl, int id)
    {
        Session["temp_data"] = id;
        return RedirectToAction(act, ctrl);
    }
}
```

**3. Use it in the action method without the parameter:**

```
public ActionResult ProfileView()
    {
        if (Session["temp_data"] == null)
        {
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }

        int id = (int)Session["temp_data"];
        var model = GetUserById(id);

        return View(model);
    }
```

So it works just fine, however, this way to hide parameters doesn't handle the case where let's say I go to a first profile(id 4), and then go to a second one(id 8). If from the second profile I press the back button on the navigator trying to go back to the first profile(id 4), I'm going to be redirected to the current profile(id 8), since 8 is the current value of the `Session["temp_data"]`.

Is there a way to handle this perticular case? Or is the another totally different and better way to hide parameters in the URL?

Thank you!

Comment: The big question is, why is it necessary to hide the query string parameters in the first place? Presumably, the user in question is authorized to view both pages. If you are trying to prevent a URL manipulation attack, there are better ways of doing that by using authorization (roles), but that may require a fundamental redesign of your architecture.

Comment: @howcheng thanks for the quick reply. You're right. I am already using authorizations and therefore I don't need to always hide the parameters. I will only hide them if ever I want to pass an object as a parameter! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that since I am already using authorizations and roles within my application, I don't need to always hide the parameters. I can simply hide whenever I am passing a complex object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead of Session

```
TempData["temp_data"]
```

Comment: [Difference between Session and TempData Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/tempdata-vs-session-in-mvc1)

Comment: From what I read, data stored in TempData is for single use only, so wouldn't it reproduce the same issue I'm having?

Comment: TempData doesnt send your id or data to your client so i will not be showed in the url. The singleuse only mean per request, it will work for all the recuest and redirections inside the controller.